# Matrix Low Rank Approximation using Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, svd

Consider a 256 x 256 matrix `A`. I'm familiar with how to calculate low rank approximations of `A` using the SVD.

Typically after using `[U S V] = svd(A)`, I would use `Ak = U(:,1:k)*S(1:k,1:k)*V(:,1:k)';` to get the rank `k` approximation of `A`.

My question is how do I create a vector `E` such that,
`E(k) = norm(A-Ak)` for `k=1,2,3.....,256`. That is `E` is a column vector of 256 elements each of which is `norm(A-Ak)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is simply

```
diag(S)
```

Why?

There's a [theorem](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/low-rank-approximations-1.html)<sup>1</sup> that says that the error between a matrix `A` and its rank-`k` approximation `Ak` has a (spectral) norm<sup>2</sup> given by the `k+1`-th singular value of `A`. That is, the error is given by the first *not used* singular value. Isn't it a wonderful<sup>3</sup> result?

Example:

```
>> A = randn(8,8);
>> [U S V] = svd(A);
>> k = 5;
>> Ak = U(:,1:k)*S(1:k,1:k)*V(:,1:k)'; %'// rank-5 approximation 
>> norm(A-Ak) %// its associated error norm
ans =
    1.0590

>> k = 6;
>> Ak = U(:,1:k)*S(1:k,1:k)*V(:,1:k)'; %'// rank-6 approximation
>> norm(A-Ak) %// its associated error norm
ans =
    0.3924

>> diag(S).' %'// all error norms
ans =
    4.5528    3.2398    2.5863    2.2031    1.4252    1.0590    0.3924    0.1021
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>
Actually I didn't know about such theorem until a few minutes ago. I just computed `norm(A-Ak)` and noticed the resulting value was in `S`. *Then* I thought there must be a theorem that established this.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>
Thanks to [@AlgebraicPavel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1694451/algebraic-pavel) for the correction.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup>
"*Algebra is generous; she often gives more than is asked of her.*" — [Jean le Rond d'Alembert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_le_Rond_d%27Alembert)</sub>

Comment: Actually, there's a mistake/typo on that linked page. The distance to the closest rank-k approximation is indeed the `k+1`-th singular value, but when measured in the spectral norm (which is what Matlab's `norm` computes by default), not the Frobenius one;  see, e.g., [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem).